# I am not able to use my models.py data in views.py that I want to display in as html

Tags: python, django

When I open the django app and view the site 
check is visible but nothing from my model is printed 
I want to display the data that I have stored in the customers model in the html file

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.

class Customer(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
Status =models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True, null=True)
def __str__(self):
return self.name
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from Core.models import Customer


def user_profile(request):
    data = Customer.objects.all() 
return render_to_response(request,"templates/home.html", {"data": data})
```

## home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Video Page
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}


{% for customer in data %}
    <h1> {{ customer.name}}</h1>
{% endfor %}


    <h1>check</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: Do you actually have data in the database?

Comment: what about using render instead of render_to_response?

Comment: use `{% empty %} No data {% endfor %}` instead of `{% endfor %}` or set breakpoints, it is likely that you don't have any data.

Comment: no data displays no data on the page but i have added data  in the customers model on the admin website how do I display that data

Comment: someone help please

Comment: try writing `print(data)` before return to check if the model returns data, make sure that the model's route is correct `from Core.models import Customer`

Answer (score 1):

> use render instead of render_to_response

```
def user_profile(request):
    data = Customer.objects.all() 
    return render(request,"templates/home.html", {"data": data})
```